# where to find resource for OSWorkflow

Tags: jira

JIRA uses OSWorkflow internally. Unfortunately, opensymphony project doesn't exist anymore. Do anybody know where to find some info about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in WebArchive: http://web.archive.org/web/20110109183255/http://www.opensymphony.com/osworkflow/Manual.html

P.S. This is answered also in Atlassian Jira ticket: [JRASERVER-24846](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-24846)